# Rails does not load assets located in public directory in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

Hello i have assets in public directory (because of simplicity)

in layout i load

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in Development it works well but in Production assets are not loaded.

My **Development.rb**

```
Web::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

My **Production.rb**

```
Web::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true # default false, zobrazuje errory
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false # default true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true # default false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because you have

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

in your `production.rb` file.

From the [Rails Configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> - **`config.serve_static_assets`** configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won´t be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

And like that guide suggests, you really shouldn't rely on serving assets from `public/` via your Rails app, it is better to let the web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) handle serving assets for performance.

Comment: thank it works but i dont get it.. i want nginx to handle my files.. thats normal behavior.. i dont have assets in assets folder (rails handle it and compile) so i want webserver to handle it (public directory).. i dont understand that compilation stuffs, so many errors because i tryed and this is far more easier

Comment: for example bootstrap, i dont want use gems because i want use themes and be able to edit it and that brings a lot of complications use assets folder. (i tried some js extension and they dont even compile, only in on the fly compilation it runs)

Comment: You can certainly continue to use the `public/` directory to manually manage your assets. The only thing you do to make this work, though, is configure Nginx to use your app's `public` directory as its document root, and then when you access your app via Nginx (and hence running with the 'production' environment) Nginx should be serving your assets.

Comment: In `development.rb` this should be set to `true` otherwise the files in the `public/` directory like `favicon.ico` will not be served.

Comment: Just I want to point out that config. serve_static_assets  is now deprecated in favour of config.serve_static_files .

Answer (score 33):

Configuration changed for Rails 4 and 5.

For Rails 4:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

For Rails 5:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```