# Rails public folder items not available in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, https, favicon

I have a few items that are accessible just fine in development mode within the `/public` directory of my app: `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt`.

I can view these in development at e.g. `localhost:3000/favicon.ico`.  However, when I push up to production, the assets are not visible at those paths.  As a result, I don't have a favicon icon and google can't find my robots.txt file, among other things.

How can I fix this so that the `/public` directory is accessible through relevant urls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails does not load assets located in public directory in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806537/rails-does-not-load-assets-located-in-public-directory-in-production)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Rails 4.2+ (non-Heroku)

`config/environments/production.rb` contains the line:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

It means you can set `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` environment variable

(pass a command line when you starts your rails server, e.g.:)

`RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=yes rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`

## Heroku

For Heroku use the `rails_12factor` gem for production in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

## Rails 4.1 and below (the old way)

Add following line in your `app/config/environments/production.rb`

```
    config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Here's what Rails Guides has to say

> config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static
> assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned
> off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the
> application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
> setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
> testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won´t
> be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly
> under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm on Heroku and this wasn't possible in early Rails 3. Now it is actually possible ("required" according to Heroku) and it is enabled by the `rails_on_heroku` gem.  See https://github.com/heroku/rails_on_heroku & https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-4-x-applications

Comment: And it's twice today! Any chance you're looking for a job?

Comment: `rails_on_heroku` is now deprecated. This is the new gem: `rails_12factor`

Comment: Please **never** use `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production for Rails. Static assets should be served by a webserver, not by rails itself. This option is useful only in development where you don't want to installa a webserver on your local machine.

Answer (score 25):

## Rails 5.1

Add following line in your `app/config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

### Updated

`config/environments/production.rb` contains the line:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

It means you can pass `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` in a command line when you starts your rails server, e.g.:

```
RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=yes rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Comment: My Puma server is just serving empty files in production mode. This setting just means it serves a 200 status instead of a 404, but always empty. Does anyone else have this issue?