# rails environment production not working no files loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in my Rails application all my js and css is in public folder.

in dev mode it works fine. but when I switch to production mode it dosn't work 
no css and js is found.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Is there are reason why you've put your js and css in the public folder vs. using the asset pipeline?

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails does not load assets located in public directory in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806537/rails-does-not-load-assets-located-in-public-directory-in-production)

Comment: has not solved my problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable this behaviour for production. Within `config/environments/production.rb`, set the following

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: dosn't changes anything. restarted the server nothing changed

Comment: assets is deprecated ... tried it with config.serve_static_files = true but also no changes

Comment: What server are you running under in production?

Comment: webrick server  is running

Answer (score 2):

In your `app/config/environments/production.rb`, check if the following statement is present:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: assets is deprecated ... tried it with config.serve_static_files = true but also no changes

Comment: @Felix I think you need to precompile your assets to make it available in production `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and change `config.serve_static_assets = true` to `config.serve_static_files = true`

Comment: tried but nothing changed ... and in public/assets there are no files

Comment: @Felix Since you are using Webrick in production, you need to precompile your assets. You have to add your assets in `config/application.rb`  as  `config.assets.precompile += %w(your_cssfile.css your_jsfile.js )` and the run the rake task to precompile it. I think then only you can access your static assets.

Comment: and why is this so? gonna try it. I have to add each single file in application.rb?

Comment: @Felix If you precompile your assets, then all the assets that have been required from your `application.js` and `application.css` are precompiled. But if you wish to add any additional assets to be precompiled then you can add them to `application.rb` as I have mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: I normally don't want precompile them ... added those with stylesheet_tag to layout ... why do I have to precompile them? do I really need to do this?

Comment: @Felix In production environment , you have to precompile the assets otherwise they wouldn't be available to use.

Comment: i've done the precompiling, but nothing changed. My files are located under public/fonts public/stylesheets/ public/javascript ... how do I precompile them properly?

Comment: I've added this:     config.assets.precompile += %w(public/style.css) to application.rb then I run rake assets:precompile ... nothing changed